# How to record requests in laravel to create tests?

Tags: laravel

Is there an easy way of saving requests in laravel in order to convert them into tests?

Sometimes all I need is checking that all routes work, list, search, show, post, patch, destroy, etc

Writing request params by hand is slow and tedious

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dd($request->txt_inputname)` on your controller to debug your request. This a native laravel function.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd